# Problem with a TinyOBJLoader Renderer

Tags: opengl, c++, models

I was working on implementing a renderer for SYOYO's tiny obj loader and when it came to testing time, it failed to render. Here is an image of the result:

[image]

I believe that i have made the error with my renderer, in which i have no idea of what is wrong.

Here is the code for the renderer:

```
void flushTerrain() {
            while (!pr_Models.empty()) {
                const Model3D* model = pr_Models.front();

                model->getVAO()->bind();

                glm::mat4 a;
                glm::translate(a, glm::vec3(model->getPosition()));

                model->getShader().setUniformMat4("ml_matrix", a);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model->getShapeVerticies().size());

                model->getVAO()->unbind();

                pr_Models.pop_front();
            }
        }
```

and the code for the Model3D Constructor:

```
Model3D(std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes, std::vector<tinyobj::material_t> materials ,glm::vec3 position, Shader& shader) :
            pr_shapes(shapes), pr_materials(materials), pr_position(position), pr_shader(shader)
        {
            pr_VAO = new VertexArray();
            for (tinyobj::shape_t shape : pr_shapes) {
                pr_VAO->addBuffer(new Buffer(shape.mesh.positions, shape.mesh.positions.size(), 3), 1);

                pr_VAO->addBuffer(new Buffer(shape.mesh.texcoords, shape.mesh.texcoords.size(), 2), 2);
                pr_VAO->addBuffer(new Buffer(shape.mesh.normals, shape.mesh.normals.size(), 3), 3);
            }
        }
```

and finally, for the Buffer and VertexArray class:

```
Buffer::Buffer(tinyobj::shape_t data, GLsizei count, GLuint componentCount) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &pr_BufferID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pr_BufferID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, count * sizeof(tinyobj::shape_t), &data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

void VertexArray::addBuffer(Buffer* buffer, GLuint index) {
        bind();
        buffer->bind();

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(index);
        glVertexAttribPointer(index, buffer->getCount(), GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        buffer->unbind();
        unbind();
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure: Number of vertexes=3*Number of Triangles when using gldrawelement(GL_TRANGLES,...